# How to find earliest and latest dates from a CSV File [Python]

Tags: python, csv

My CSV file is arranged so that there's a row named "Dates," and below that row is a gigantic column of a million dates, in the traditional format like "4/22/2015" and "3/27/2014".

How can I write a program that identifies the earliest and latest dates in the CSV file, while maintaining the original format (month/day/year)?

I've tried

```
for line in count_dates:
    dates = line.strip().split(sep="/")
    all_dates.append(dates)

print (all_dates)
```

I've tried to take away the "/" and replace it with a blank space, but it does not print anything.

Comment: post the code that you tried.

Comment: Also, please post a representative sample of your csv file

Comment: Please note that the date format that you are describing is the US format - month/day/year - the UK and many other places use day/month/year and the "traditional" format for computers is either yearmonthday or a floating point number starting from a specific date, (that unfortunately is not the same for all operating systems).

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a large file, reading it in its entirety into memory is a bad idea.

Read the file line by line, manually keeping track of the earliest and latest dates. Use [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the strings to dates (takes the string format as parameter.

```
import datetime
with open("input.csv") as f:
  f.readline() # get the "Dates" header out of the way
  first = f.readline().strip()
  earliest = datetime.datetime.strptime(first, "%m/%d/%Y")
  latest = datetime.datetime.strptime(first, "%m/%d/%Y")
  for line in f:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(), "%m/%d/%Y")
    if date < earliest: earliest = date
    if date > latest: latest = date
  print "Earliest date:", earliest
  print "Latest date:", latest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(lambda v: datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%m/%d/%Y'))
print df['Dates'].min(), df['Dates'].max()
```

Comment: Bad idea to read the entire file into memory, considering it's a large file.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an RTFM answer: Open the file in csv format (see the csv library), and then iterate line by line converting the field that is a date into a date object (see the docs for converting a string to a date object), and if it is less than minimum so far store it as minimum, similar for max, with a special condition on the first line that the date becomes both min and max dates.

Or for some overkill you could just use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to read it into a data frame specifying the specific column as date format then just use max & min.

Comment: FTRM = F*** The Reading Material?

Comment: Thanks to EvenLisle for correcting my Acronymic Dyslexia - my excuse is that it as 06:00 here - just waking up!

Answer (score 0):

Let's open the csv file, read out all the dates. Then use `strptime` to turn them into comparable datetime objects (now, we can use `max`). Lastly, let's print out the biggest (latest) date

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    dt.strftime(max(dt.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y") \
                    for row in csv.reader(infile)), \
                "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Naturally, you can use `min` to get the earliest date. However, this takes two linear runs, and you can do this with just one, if you are willing to do some heavy lifting yourself:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    date, *_rest = next(infile)
    date = dt.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")

    for date, *_rest in reader:
        date = dt.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        earliest = min(date, earliest)
        latest = max(date, latest)
    print("earliest:", dt.strftime(earliest, "%m/%d/%Y"))
    print("latest:", dt.strftime(latest, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: how to check for the weekday of any particular date?

Comment: @desmond.carros: `datetime.strftime` has a formatting option to output the name of the weekday

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more convenient to use pandas for this purpose.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
df['name_of_column_with_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['name_of_column_with_date'], format='%-m/%d/%Y')

print('min_date{}'.format(min(df['name_of_column_with_date'])))
print('max_date{}'.format(max(df['name_of_column_with_date'])))
```

The built-in functions work well with Pandas Dataframes.

For more understanding of the format feature in `pd.to_datatime` you can use [Python `strftime` cheat sheet](https://strftime.org/)